# Ambiguous use of Subscript Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Since updating the latest Xcode, I've started to get the following error occurring "Ambiguous use of Subscript" related to this piece of code;

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("postsCell") as! CustomTableViewCell!
        if cell == nil {
            cell = CustomTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "postsCell")
        }
        let dict:NSDictionary = arrPosts[indexPath.row]

        if let postResourceName = dict["resource_name"]![0] as! String? where !postResourceName.isEmpty {
            cell?.customPostTitle?.text = String(htmlEncodedString: postResourceName)
        } else if let postTitle = dict["title"]!["rendered"] as? String {
            cell?.customPostTitle?.text = String(htmlEncodedString: postTitle)
        }
```

Specifically on this line;

```
if let postResourceName = dict["resource_name"]![0] as! String? where !postResourceName.isEmpty {
```

I'm quite new to Swift, I believe this relates to the lack of detail around a variable type which is why the error is being thrown. But I'm unsure as to what the code should be.

Any pointers?

Regards,
Michael

Comment: Ambiguous use of subscript means that the compiler can not infer the proper type because a value from a dictionary is always `AnyObject`. How is `arrPosts` declared? And If you're new to Swift (re-)read the paragraph about `Optional binding` in the language guide carefully.

Comment: The initial variable for arrPosts is defined as follows; var arrPosts = [[String:AnyObject]]()

Answer (score 0):

Swift compiler gives you that error because is does not know what objects do you have as `values` in you dictionary, so when you do `dict["resource_name"]![0]` you want to access the first item of the array contained in the dictionary as a `value`. But you never tell that your values are arrays so the type of the `values` is `AnyObject`. You could specify that you have `Array` in your dictionary by replacing

```
let dict:NSDictionary = arrPosts[indexPath.row]
```

with

```
let dict = arrPosts[indexPath.row] as [String:[String]]
```

Comment: Thanks, just tried this and I'm getting the following error now on the same line; Reference to generic type 'Array' requires arguments in <...>

The initial variable for arrPosts is defined as follows, if this makes any difference?;

var arrPosts = [[String:AnyObject]]()

Comment: Needed an 'as' changing to 'as!', this has solved this one though. As usual, leading to other errors being flagged. Time to work through these now.